# Looking for software that will compress, encrypt, split, and upload data for backups to multiple clouds

Tags: 13.04, backup, cloud

As the title says, I'm looking for Ubuntu friendly software that will compress, encrypt, split, and upload data for backups across multiple clouds. I have grabbed multiple cloud accounts for free ranging from 2gb to 50gb in size and I'd like to backup my data encrypted to those clouds. Some of these accounts includ dropbox, box.net, microsoft skydrive, google drive, and others. All of my systems are running Ubuntu 13.04 Raring. Any ideas?

Comment: For the compression and encryption part you could simply use ``7z``. It supports 256-bit AES encryption with the ``7z -p -mhe``

Comment: Just note 7z doesn't store file permissions

Answer (score 1):

The downside to using a bunch of services is that your storage is fragmented, but a benefit in that is if you isolate the types of files you back up with each service, you know exactly where to find them.  The other downside is that you'll have a few apps running processes on your system all at once. For the most part this should work just fine so long as you don't try to alter files at the same time.

The only thing that I could find that comes close is called Duplicati.

> Duplicati is a free backup client that securely stores encrypted,
>   incremental, compressed backups on cloud storage services and remote
>   file servers. It works with Amazon S3, Windows Live SkyDrive, Google
>   Drive (Google Docs), Rackspace Cloud Files or WebDAV, SSH, FTP (and
>   many more). <sup>Source:Duplicati</sup>

For more information, and to download, visit their [Website](http://www.duplicati.com/news/duplicati134available).

Extra reading [Five tools to help sync more than one cloud storage service](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tools-to-help-sync-more-than-one-cloud-storage-service/1835), and [How to encrypt your cloud storage for free](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2010296/how-to-encrypt-your-cloud-storage-for-free.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was using Dropbox (there is not enough free space for me), Sugarsync (same like Dropbox, and for me slow).

Now I am using new service - Copy. They will give you 15GB for free.

If you register on Copy by this link, and install their application to backup / sync your data, you will get 20GB for free!
Here is the link: https://copy.com?r=zPku0e

Bonus for you is, that if you will find some referral, you will get next 5GB for free per each! Like this, you can get unlimited space for free!